# Upgrading an application deployed to hosted service using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

Would like to know how can i upgrade a single role of deployment application on hosted service using REST API.let say I have 2 web and 1 worker role and i would like to update/upgrade only one webrole out of 2 .I know that we can do it Azure Management Portal.

Would also like to know how rollback works in Azure.If I like to rollback deployment application to previous state, can i rollback?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the number of roles using the Service Management API. This is only possible by doing a new deployment (this is possible using the API).

The only thing you can do is modifying the number of instances by using the **ChangeConfiguration** request: [Change Deployment Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx)

Rolling back a deployment to a previous state is possible [using the REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403977.aspx). What I tend to do when deploying a new version is by using a VIP swap:

- I deploy the new version of my app to staging
- I do a VIP swap (new version becomes production, old version becomes staging)
- I shut down the staging version (without deleting it), this way the old version stops processing messages from queues etc.. in case my logic changed.

If I want to roll back, I simply turn the old deployment back on and do a VIP swap again. This way of working comes with 2 remarks:

- You can only "revert" to the previous version of your app
- You need to take into account that you might have changed external resources (like SQL Azure) and rolling back the application could break because of this change

**Edit:** Modified my rolling back answer with a link to the REST API

Comment: If user added new a web role and wanted to update the same in the deployed application on hosted service,it is not possible using REST API.I am correct?

Comment: Well you can upgrade the deployment using the Service Management API. But this is only possible if you upload a new package containing the new web role: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460793

Comment: For rollback Please follow the link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/90f889ae-ec07-4f28-b22d-d2ca4dc91c2c ,it is specified that for rollback.It is specified that if there 3 instance of web role,1st&2nd is upgradeDomin0 and 3rd in upgradeDomin1.if you apply new changes to 1&2,3rd is untouched then u can rollback 1&2 to previous state..Please provide your inputs

Comment: Nice link on upgrade domains, didn't think of that!

Comment: Indeed, if you have one upgrade domain that is untouched, you should be able to rollback the other upgrade domains to their initial state.

Comment: Can i move a deployment application from  staging to production using REST API

Comment: Yes, you can Swap the deployment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460814

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by @Sandrino. Just wanted to expand on in-place updates a bit. The **Upgrade Deployment** REST API call is what you'd use for updating a role. As Sandrino pointed out, you'll still need to push a new deployment package up (which includes all roles), but you can then specify to upgrade only a single role from the entire package by specifying the role name for the `RoleToUpgrade` element.

See [this MSDN reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460793.aspx) on the Upgrade Deployment API call.

EDIT: All REST APIs are also available through PowerShell cmdlets (downloadable [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads/)). Take a look at `Set-AzureDeployment`, which has an **Upgrade** parameter set.

Comment: +1 for RoleToUpgrade, didn't notice this before but can be interesting to do partial upgrades. Does this mean you can simply leave other roles untouched?

Comment: Yep - this is part of the [improved in-place update enhancements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx) that were announced in October 2011.

Comment: Thanks @SandrinoDiMattia,@David for your valuable inputs..I really appreciate it.